# Controller action with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am trying to understand what ***I think*** is a model binding problem in my ASP.NET Core project.  I have the following 'Index' controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SortFilterIndexOptions options) { ... }
```

The `SortFilterIndexOptions` are four members defined in the following class:

```
public class SortFilterIndexOptions
{
    public int SelectedBirdId { get; set; }
    public bool ShowAll { get; set; }
    public bool ShowInTable { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
}
```

These enable the user to filter a paged index page.  The bool members are linked to checkbox controls.

I have a fault if the 'ShowAll' bool member is changed to TRUE and then try to navigate to a different page. As the screenshot, below, shows the 'ShowAll' parameter part of the url then contains two bool values ('ShowAll=true, false'):

[image]

which of course results in a parse error ('FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean').

What's happening here?  It only happens when the 'ShowAll' parameter is toggled to TRUE.  Is it a routing problem because it does not follow the default route pattern? Or is it a problem with the ModelBinder?  I am just trying to understand what is going on so I can take the right action.  Any help would be appreciated...

**Update**

This is now issue [#3246](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3246) ('ModelBinding error with boolean values') on the asp/Home GitHub repository (originally raised by me as issue [#1711](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1711) on the dotnet/Core repository).

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...`ShowAll=true,false` is not valid as a boolean. Should work with just `ShowAll=true`

Comment: Is this a checkbox in a form which is sent through GET?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to work out why it adding the two Boolean values. When I click the next page button. This happens the ShowAll is toggled to true. Why is it appending the second ‘false’ value in the url?

Comment: @CodeCaster. It is a Bootstrap Toggle control. So the same as a checkbox. In a form to a GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was investigated by the aspnet/Mvc team under issue [#8043](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8043).

There is no problem with the ModelBinder.  The problem was caused by my pager code, which constructs the url.  Please use the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8043) to view the full conversation which contains a detailed explanation from the aspnet/Mvc team and sample code provided by me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear...`ShowAll=true,false` is not valid as a Boolean.

The model binder is receiving the following string `"true,false"` from the query string for that parameter and would then try to parse that as a Boolean, which would fail as you have already seen.

Similar to trying

```
bool value = bool.Parse("true,false");
```

Should work with just `ShowAll=true`

Comment: [_"When the checkbox is checked, the ModelBinder will automatically take care of extracting the 'true' from the 'true,false'"_](https://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster I am wondering now if the model binder in core has that capability?

Comment: Well I know core likes to break a lot of things, but something as fundamental as a checkbox on a form...?

Comment: Yes it seems odd. I will change to a drop down list of enumerated values and see if it works.  To try to see if the fault is isolated to the checkbox...  As I mentioned, one can navigate the different pages of the checkboxes are left as false. It breaks when one is switched to true...

Comment: I replaced the checkboxes with drop down lists and the model binding issue was resolved.  Which suggests the issue was caused by the ModelBinder with checkboxes.  I will leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone can add anything...